# arrange resulting loop row values into one array in matlab

Tags: matlab, scripting

Considering the fact that i have gotten some clarity on this current question, I have edited the code to conform with my current problem with the code. So now the problem i have with my code is that it does not loop any more. if i place a for loop and some conditions, the value of `groups` which is supposed to change with every loop does not therefore causing an error at `k is 2` in the loop. The initial value of `groups` is gotten from the first part of the code which gets its value form a different array, but the for loop part of the code is supposed to use that initial `groups`value and then continue changing from there. that is where the problem comes, as the value of `groups` refuses to change.

```
   A = connections;
% Engine
tic
[m, n] = size(A);
groups = [];
ng = 0;

 k=1;
    w= 1:2:3;
    u = unique(A(k,w)); % representation of kth row
    [in, J] = ismember(A(k:end,:),u);
    l = m-k+1;
    r = repmat((1:l).', n, 1);
    c = accumarray([r(in) J(in)],1,[l n]); % count
    c = bsxfun(@min,c,c(1,:)); % clip
    rows = sum(c,2)==2; % check if 2 elements are common
    if any(rows)
        ng = +1;
        groups = (k-1) + [1; find(rows)];
    end


 gr=groups(end);
 nwrry= [A(k,:);A(gr,:)];

for k=1:5
 h=[];
    h(k)= groups(end);
      dff= setdiff(nwrry(end,:),nwrry(end-1,:));
    [rw,cl]= find(nwrry==dff);
    if cl==3
       w=1:2:cl;
    else
        if cl==2
            w=1:cl;
       else
         w=cl:2;
        end
    end
    u = unique(A(h(k),w)); % representation of kth row
    [in, J] = ismember(A(k:end,:),u);
    l = m-k+1;
    r = repmat((1:l).', n, 1);
    c = accumarray([r(in) J(in)],1,[l n]); % count
    c = bsxfun(@min,c,c(1,:)); % clip
    rows = sum(c,2)==2; % check if 2 elements are common
    if any(rows)
        ng = ng+1;
        groups = (k-1) + [1; find(rows)];
    end
       nwrry = [nwrry;A(groups(end),:)]
k=k+1
end
```

connections is the 800 by 3 array. if you want to test it and see what it gives as a result please make sure  the array has at most 2 values in a row  common with another row.

Comment: You have to index `groups` inside the loop..

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what you mean. could u please clarify@ excaza

Comment: `groups(i, :)`. See: [MATLAB's language fundamentals](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html)

Comment: i did try what you suggested, but it still gave the same outcome. ` groups`was already dimmed as an empty array so indexing it did not really cause any difference @excaza

Comment: In that case you probably need to step through your code using the debugger. It is likely that you're never getting inside the `if` block.

Comment: it does enter the if block but what it does is for each similarity it just collects them and place them in seperate groups;

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. It would be helpful if you showed us the output you're getting.

Comment: Okay so i have edited the code a bit.. So as shown above where i wrote 3 `group =......` statement. That is what the outcome is. so basically what it does is for each iteration it gives group that equals an array that adds the next row to the former one. o at the end if u have 20 steps, it will give like 20 `group =` But i don't want that i want the total thing in on group

Comment: Add a semi-colon `;` at the end of this line: `groups(k,:) = (k-1) + find(rows)`

Comment: Ithink that does not really help as when i tried it, it just doesnt show the total result of the loop, instead it chooses just one step and writes the answer. however if i do call the variable`group`, it does as i explained in the above comment

Comment: So it gives you the *total thing*! So what's the problem then? What output are you expecting?

Comment: it does at the very end, but then before it can give you that it has to give u for every single step. so for each step it makes a matrix. and when you summon the last step it only shows the value of that row not all the other rows together.

Comment: After adding a semi-colon at the end of that line, write this `groups(k,:)`

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I think you mean add the line `groups` or `disp(groups);` at the end of the existing code. If you index it with `(k,:)` you're only going to get the last row. And yes, you need the semicolon at the end of the existing `groups(k,:) = ...` line to suppress the intermediate results.

Comment: @beaker What I understood from his comments is that he wants to show only the recently calculated row. I don't think he wants `groups` or `disp(group)` at the end of his code. (saying this on the basis of his last two comments)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Oh well, I interpreted it the other way... guess we still need clarification in the original question as to what *exactly* the desired result is.

Comment: i have adjusted the question, maybe it is clearer for everyone now

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite. You're back to assigning your rows to a single variable rather than a matrix so it's getting overwritten ever time. You still haven't provided a [mcve]. You need to break this problem down to smaller parts and use the debugger to determine where your logic is going wrong. As for me, I'm done with this question. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, i have tried what you suggested and it actually helped. I will post my solution. maybe it might help someone..

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to answer this question. Thank you all who have commented with your advices and help because i did look into what you all said and been able to come up with something worthwhile.
 The complete code is below;

```
%% call connections
A= connections;
[m, n] = size(A);%% calculate number of rows (m) and columns(n) in A

%% find rows with similar values as row 1
[a, b]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(1,1));%% Find rows with similar value as the first value of row 1
[a1, b1]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(1,2));%% Find rows with similar value as the second value of row 1
[a2, b2]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(1,3));%% Find rows with similar value as the third value of row 1

%% find the rows with atleast 2 values similar to row 1
int1= intersect(a,a1);%% Find same row numbers between a and a1
int2= intersect(a,a2);%% Find same row numbers between a and a2
int3= intersect(a1,a2);%% Find same row numbers between a1 and a2
 ints=[int1;int2;int3];%% Place all intersections in one array(ints)

%% delete row number that is same with row number 1
   ints= unique(ints);%% delete repeated row numbers 
 [Lia,Locb] = ismember(ints(1:end,:),1);%% Find same row numbers same with row number 1
 [z, x]=find(Lia(1:end,:) == 1);%% Find row numbers equal to 1 in Lia
   ints(z(1:end),:)=[];%% delete row numbers that is same with row number 1

   %% place the searched row number and the similar row number in an array(gr)
  gr=1;%% Place initial row number(1) in one array(gr)
 tg=[a;a1;a2];%% Place all row numbers with similar value as row 1 in one array(tg)
 if isempty(ints)%% conditions when ints is empty
    f= setdiff(tg,gr);%% Find row numbers in tg not present in gr
    gr=[gr;f(1,:)];%% add the similar row number in array gr
 else          %% conditions when ints is NOT empty
    gr=[gr;ints(end)]; %% add the similar row number in array gr
 end

%% place the searched row  and the similar row  in an array(nwrry)
 nwrry= [A(1,:);A(gr(end),:)]; 

 %% Create loop for all rows in A and repeat all processes above
for i=1:m-2
    hrry=[];
    hrry(i)= gr(end);

   [a, b]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(hrry(end),1));
   [a1, b1]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(hrry(end),2));
   [a2, b2]=find(A(1:end,:) == A(hrry(end),3));
   int1= intersect(a,a1);
   int2= intersect(a,a2);
   int3= intersect(a1,a2);
    ints=[int1;int2;int3];
    ints= unique(ints);
 [Lia,Locb] = ismember(ints(1:end,:),gr(1:end,:));
      [z, x]=find(Lia(1:end,:) == 1);
   ints(z(1:end),:)=[];
     tg=[a;a1;a2];

 if isempty(ints)
    f= setdiff(tg,gr);
    if isempty(f)
        Anb=1:m;
        Anbc=Anb';
        nwf= setdiff(Anbc,gr);
        gr=[gr;nwf(1,:)];
    else
        gr=[gr;f(1,:)];
    end
 else
    gr=[gr;ints(end)];
end
nwrry= [nwrry;A(gr(end),:)];
end
```